# Transistor system like a shift-register?

Tags: shift-register

I'm new to electronics and need a name for a type of component that I seek.

I want to find a component that act as a shift register but with a transistor result rather than the voltage output that the shift register have.

The reasons for this is that I want to make a hack on a remote that has a [HT6222](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/206127/HOLTEK/HT6222.html) matrix keyboard decoder with IR output for remote control applications. I want to control the connections between the C and R inputs of the HT6222 (for rows and columns of keyboard).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a transistor result"?

Comment: I think he means to switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not find a shift register component with a free connect switch type output. An open collector transistor output will also not always work in a row/column switch matrix which normally requires switches with free ends.

So I would recommend that you start with a normal shift register such as the 74HC595 to provide the control I/O signals from your microcontroller. The wire the shift register outputs to the switch enable pins in a component such as the 74HC4066 quad switch type part. This part offers switches with two free ends per switch that you can easily wire into the row/column switch matrix of the remote control device.

Comment: That's how I'd approach it unless it was proven that all the switches in the rows and columns were ground based BUT that would make a nonsense of rows and columns.

Comment: @Andyaka - Indeed. I've been here before using an MCU to override a keypad. :^)